# Probability on a time basis

Tags: statistics

They were talking about volcanoes today on TV, specifically the Popocatépetl and the threat of pyroclastic flows if a Plinian eruption happened. It was mentioned that because an eruption didn't occur in 1000 years (AD 800) there is an increasing probability.
Popular science, so intuitive, but what can be calculated exactly and how?

So the question is, if we know the mean time between two events, possibly variance, and date of last occurrence, what should be used to describe the next occurrence or "threat"? Like probability on a daily basis?

This looks like a beginner's question, sorry, my last statistics class was long ago. I think that Bayes' formula is involved here but don't know how to transform the mean time to the yes/no question "will event occur today".

Comment: I'm a beginner and don't know the answer to your question and hope someone answers it. My 2 cents... I think many intro probability questions will model the time to the next eruption using the exponential distribution. But because the program said there is an increasing chance of eruption for each day that passes then you don't have the memoryless property. Maybe the answer could be like Laplace's rule of succession, where you use a Beta distribution... that comes to mind because this seems similar to the sunrise question.